# Error while importing Tensorflow. A dynamic link library (DLL) initialization routine failed

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow

I am using tensorflow CPU for a while and decided to install tf gpu and now when i try to import tf it gives me this error.
My system specs are:
Intel Xeon w5320 2.8 Ghz 8threads.
10 GB Ram
Nvidia GTX 1050 2GB
I have installed latest drivers, Cuda 9.0 and cuDNN v7.1.3 (April 17, 2018), for CUDA 9.0.
Any kind of help is appreciated.

```
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
C:\Users\Arsalan\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py in <module>()
     57 
---> 58   from tensorflow.python.pywrap_tensorflow_internal import *
     59   from tensorflow.python.pywrap_tensorflow_internal import __version__

C:\Users\Arsalan\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py in <module>()
     17         return importlib.import_module(mname)
---> 18     _pywrap_tensorflow_internal = swig_import_helper()
     19     del swig_import_helper

C:\Users\Arsalan\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py in swig_import_helper()
     16         mname = '.'.join((pkg, '_pywrap_tensorflow_internal')).lstrip('.')
---> 17         return importlib.import_module(mname)
     18     _pywrap_tensorflow_internal = swig_import_helper()

C:\Users\Arsalan\Anaconda3\lib\importlib\__init__.py in import_module(name, package)
    125             level += 1
--> 126     return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
    127 

ImportError: DLL load failed: A dynamic link library (DLL) initialization routine failed.

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-5-fe877e2db533> in <module>()
----> 1 import tensorflow as tf
      2 import numpy as np
      3 import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

C:\Users\Arsalan\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\__init__.py in <module>()
     22 
     23 # pylint: disable=wildcard-import
---> 24 from tensorflow.python import *  # pylint: disable=redefined-builtin
     25 # pylint: enable=wildcard-import
     26 

C:\Users\Arsalan\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\__init__.py in <module>()
     47 import numpy as np
     48 
---> 49 from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tensorflow
     50 
     51 # Protocol buffers

C:\Users\Arsalan\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py in <module>()
     72 for some common reasons and solutions.  Include the entire stack trace
     73 above this error message when asking for help.""" % traceback.format_exc()
---> 74   raise ImportError(msg)
     75 
     76 # pylint: enable=wildcard-import,g-import-not-at-top,unused-import,line-too-long

ImportError: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Arsalan\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 58, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.pywrap_tensorflow_internal import *
  File "C:\Users\Arsalan\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 18, in <module>
    _pywrap_tensorflow_internal = swig_import_helper()
  File "C:\Users\Arsalan\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 17, in swig_import_helper
    return importlib.import_module(mname)
  File "C:\Users\Arsalan\Anaconda3\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
ImportError: DLL load failed: A dynamic link library (DLL) initialization routine failed.


Failed to load the native TensorFlow runtime.

See https://www.tensorflow.org/install/install_sources#common_installation_problems

for some common reasons and solutions.  Include the entire stack trace
above this error message when asking for help.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following script has helped me pinpoint what was wrong on my installation of Tensorflow GPU on Windows: https://gist.github.com/diarabit/17d9051f9505c9d554d8a7d0c2bc4eb1
I hope this will help you too.

Best regards.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. Answers that are little more than a link may be deleted. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers

Comment: @Spangen I understand, I will try and explain what the script actually does so that future users may do the same by hand. I will try to do it by tomorrow.

Comment: All required DLLs appear to be present. Please open an issue on the
  TensorFlow GitHub page: https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues
An exception has occurred, use %tb to see the full traceback.

Comment: This script is mostly useful for GPU versions of TF. For CPU versions, it won't help much.

Answer (score 2):

https://github.com/rohit-patel/Install_Instructions-Win10-Deeplearning-Keras-Tensorflow
I followed this post precisely and got it working.
Actual problem was i didn't have a CPU with AVX and i needed to install tensorflow 1.5 with compatible CUDA and cudNN.
I hope it solves everyone's problem.
Thanks.